# Redux state is not persisting

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, nodes

I am trying to reset the password of the user (Forget password)

for that I am doing

1. Getting email of user (setting email in redux store)
2. Sending link to that mail
3. At that link getting new password (email from redux store)

Problem is that after setting email in redux store I am not able to get that value from store when i open link that was send to mail.

My store is showing other values at that link but not the email which I set immediately before 2nd step

1st step getting email address from user

```
....

            this.props.setEmail(this.state.email)
axios.post('/forgetEmail/',{"email":this.state.email})
                .then((res)=>{
                console.log(res)
            })
....

var mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{
    return{
        setEmail:(data)=>dispatch({type:'SET_USER_EMAIL',payload:data})
    }
}

export default connect((state)=>{return state},mapDispatchToProps)(Footer)
```

My reducer

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function AuthReducer(state={isAuth:false},action){



 ...
else if(action.type === 'SET_USER_EMAIL'){
            console.log("dsdasd")
            console.log("seting email",action.payload)
            return Object.assign({},state,{email:action.payload})
        }
        return state
    }
```

requesting

```
Router.get('/passWordForget/:param1',(reqs,resp)=>{
    console.log("heh")
    console.log(reqs.params)
    resp.statusCode = 302;
    var token = reqs.params.param1

    jwt.verify(token,"aseceratetoken",(err,decoded)=>{
        if(err){
            resp.setHeader("Location", `http://localhost:3000/`);
        }else{
            reqs.cookie('vstring',token)
            resp.setHeader("Location", `http://localhost:3000/#/newPassword/`);
        }   
    })
  resp.end();
})
```

getting new password (here **this.state.user.email is undefined** )

```
constructor(props){
            super(props)



        this.state = {
            email:this.props.user.email,
            password:'',
            passwordVerify:''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }
var mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    return {
        user:state.Auth
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewPass

)
```

my combine reducer / rootReducer file

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux'

import Auth from './Auth.js'
import {loadState} from './loadState.js'

const presistState = loadState()

var rootReducer = combineReducers({
    Auth
})

export default rootReducer
```

I have spend huge time searching for solution any help is welcome thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers) to merge all reducers.

Instead of `user:state.Auth`,it should be `user:state.Auth.email`

```
var mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
        return {
            user:state.Auth.email // put email here with reducers key
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanku brother. I don't know why this was the problem. Initially i have many reducers and to access their state i store by {user:state.user} and they are working fine but here can you explain why i have to set {user:state.user.email}. thankyou many many

Comment: when you are using combineReducers,state is getting mapped to respected reducers and can be access using reducers key name used in combinedRedicers.